# Efficient solver of a Integer programming

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, convex-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, nonconvex

I am solving an Integer programming using MATLAB, yet the efficiency is low.
Here is the problem:

Suppose $v$ is a $N \times 1$ vector. For $v_i \in v$, $v_i \in \{0,1\}$.
$D$ is a 0-1 matrix, which means for each $d_{ij} \in D$, $d_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$.

The translation of this problem is to make element $1$ in $v$ to be  as few as possible when the constraints are met.
\begin{equation}  
\begin{split}  
&\min \left\|\boldsymbol{v}\right\|_2 \\  
&s.t.\  \begin{array}{c}  
D\boldsymbol{v} \ge \boldsymbol{1}\\
\end{array}  
\end{split}  
\label{eq:core_op}
\end{equation}

Is there a good solver for this kind of problem in the field of optimization?

Comment: Did you try with Gurobi?

Comment: @nicoguaro Will that be faster than MATLAB or Ceres?

Comment: Cplex is also one of the fastest solvers. What you can do aswell is to check if D is a totally unimodular matrix, because then the linear programming relaxation solves your IP.

Comment: I don't know. It is a fast solver. You could give it a try.

Comment: This is a set covering problem, for which there's a huge literature.  It's NP-Hard, so don't expect to find a solver that scales well to larger problems.